# How to retrieve code from .sikuli folder?

Tags: sikuli

When I open a `.sikuli` folder, it only has images in it.  So I want to know whether there is any way that I can see or retrieve the Sikuli code without using Sikuli IDE.

Can I get to it from a `.sikuli` folder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://doc.sikuli.org/devs/system-design.html#the-structure-of-a-sikuli-source-executable-script-sikuli-skl):

> A Sikuli script (.sikuli) is a directory that consists of a Python
>   source file (.py), and all the image files (.png) used by the source
>   file. All images used in a Sikuli script are simply a path to the .png
>   file in the .sikuli bundle. Therefore, the Python source file can also
>   be edited by any text editor.

So, there is a `.py` source file also, and, of course, you can use your favorite editor to write sikuli scripts.

Hope that helps.