# how to Load captured image in sikuli?

Tags: sikuli

How to load captured image from a location into sikuli script and make it clickable.

here is what I am doing:

- open pp
- capture desired image
- save it to some location

Now I want to load that captured image and make it clickable in code, so that functions in that carpeted image can be used as needed.

please assist... Or any work around will be much appreciated.

My Code

```
openApp('Safari') App.focus("Safari") 
wait(10) 
import shutil
import os 
dir = "imgpath" wait(5) 
image = capture() 
name = input("abc") 
newimg = os.path.join(dir, name + ".png") 
shutil.move(image, newimg)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve code from .sikuli folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771027/how-to-retrieve-code-from-sikuli-folder)